# Error message "You must configure the G Suite Marketplace SDK to publish an add-on." when SDK is correctly configured

Tags: google-apps-script

I have published tens of add-ons but now suddenly when doing everything the same way I get the error message "You must configure the G Suite Marketplace SDK to publish an add-on." when I try to publish an add-on using the "Deploy as Docs add-on" menu item. I have configured the "G Suite Marketplace SDK". BTW, the error dialog presenting the error message is linking to the console project correctly but the link replaces the current browser document, it would be better if it would open a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

The message in the dialog is not an error message. They have changed the way you start the publish process. The dialog would make more sense to me if it would say:

We have changed the publish process:

1. Go to your console project
2. Enable the G Suite Marketplace SDK library
3. Configure the Marketplace SDK with the Config tab
4. Publish the add-on using the Publish tab

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25040683)

Comment: I was commenting on my own post. Am I missing something?

Comment: You should use the "add comment" link if it's a comment, or (probably better) edit your original question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a feature request to Google about the Apps Script code editor, then you'll need to use the [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)

[Make Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113)

[image: Apps Script Feature Request]

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*Google is currently migrating add-ons from the Chrome Web Store to the G Suite Marketplace, so now need to be published there rather than the legacy marketplace.*

#### Further Information:

In order to publish an Apps Script project as an addon, as specified in your message, the G Suite Marketplace SDK must be configured. You can find an article detailing the migration process [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration).

You will need to enable the G Suite Marketplace SDK in your Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project. You can follow the information on the [Getting Started](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started?ref_topic=6262490&visit_id=637122836455358016-4288036907&rd=1) page for Google Cloud.

#### References:

- [All add-ons now in the G Suite Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/cws-migration)
- [Publish to the G Suite Marketplace](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/listing-gsm)
- [Getting Started with Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started?ref_topic=6262490&visit_id=637122836455358016-4288036907&rd=1)